# Wordpress title, specific font and a dash character

Tags: wordpress, font-face, custom-post-type, title

I have a problem in Wordpress, which I have never experienced before.

I have a title on a Custom Post Type post with a title containing a dash (-). This title has a specifik font implemented with font-face, and it all works fine. Except for the dash character. When i post the title with either `the_title();`, `echo get_the_title();` or `single_post_title();` it shows the title without the dash (-).

The font works perfectly everywhere else even with dashes and other characters. The problem only occurs with post titles and this specific font.

Sure, I could just use another font, but the client really want to use this font. And I'm quite curious to find the reason to this weird behavior.

Have anyone else experienced this or know a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a link to the post in question? What font are you using, which browser is rendering the dash incorrectly?

Comment: Yes. Here it is: [link](http://html24-dev.dk/enteneller/events/er-gode-rad-ikke-dyre-de-er-ganske-gratis/) It's in the title "Sådan! Max værdi – og effekt!" You can't see the dash (-), but it's there. I'm using Titillium Text, and itø's rendering incorrectly in all browsers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... the title you mentioned seems to be rendering the dash, ndash and mdash properly in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari Win. Did you fix this somehow?

Comment: Yeah. I re-downloaded and re-implemented the font on the site, and did some tweaks with the font. I don't know what the problem was, but it is fixed now. Something was wrong broken in the font somehow. Thanks for taking the time to look at it though :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a specific font for a dash character? A dash is a dash, your font face files dont have that particular glyph so you would wrap the dash in a span tag and apply a different font to that span via CSS.

Well thats what I would do, the client won't know the difference!

Comment: No no. I'm just using a specific font for the whole title. I could write some javascript og php that wrapped the dash in a span and used a different font. But I don't want to use a hax like this. And, there must be a solution to fix this.